# Add Metadata to created bitmap in Android

Tags: android, android-camera, metadata

I am using a camera intent to take pictures, then I convert that image to a bytearray and eventually save it locally in my database. The original image taken with the camera has all the metadata like GPS latitude and longtitude etc. However, the bitmap I create from that image does not include any meta data. How can I add the original metedata to my image ?

Here is my code where the camera intent returns:

```
picUri = data.getData()    
Bitmap yourSelectedImage62 = null;
                String imagebytes2 ;
                try
                {
                    yourSelectedImage62 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), picUri);
                    yourSelectedImage62 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourSelectedImage62, large_width, large_height, true);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
                {
                    Logger.getLogger(Screen_View_Submission.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Screen_New_Submission.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

                ByteArrayOutputStream bao62 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                yourSelectedImage62.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bao62);
                byte[] ba62 = bao62.toByteArray();
                imagebytes2 = Base64.encodeToString(ba62,Base64.DEFAULT);
                yourSelectedImage62.recycle();
```

Answer (score 2):

Meta data is not a property of bitmap. it is stored as Exinf of JPEG file. use [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) to update meta data here is an example to set gps cordinates

```
exif = new ExifInterface(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
        int num1Lat = (int) Math.floor(latitude);
        int num2Lat = (int) Math.floor((latitude - num1Lat) * 60);
        double num3Lat = (latitude - ((double) num1Lat + ((double) num2Lat / 60))) * 3600000;

        int num1Lon = (int) Math.floor(longitude);
        int num2Lon = (int) Math.floor((longitude - num1Lon) * 60);
        double num3Lon = (longitude - ((double) num1Lon + ((double) num2Lon / 60))) * 3600000;

        exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, num1Lat + "/1," + num2Lat + "/1," + num3Lat + "/1000");
        exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE, num1Lon + "/1," + num2Lon + "/1," + num3Lon + "/1000");

        if (latitude > 0) {
            exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF, "N");
        } else {
            exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF, "S");
        }

        if (longitude > 0) {
            exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF, "E");
        } else {
            exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF, "W");
        }
        exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MAKE, "FooBarr");
        exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MODEL, "KooKKoo");
        exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,orientation+"");
        exif.saveAttributes();
```