# Add metadata to image

Tags: android

I would like to add metadata to images when images are clicked on e.g. date, time taken, and a description part where the user can add their own note.

```
if (requestCode == GALLERY_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null)
    {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        imageUri = data.getData();
        File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), bubbleName);
        imagesFolder.mkdirs();

        File destFile = new File(imagesFolder, "bodypart_" + timeStamp + ".png");
        try {
            copyFile(new File(getPath(imageUri)), destFile);
            imagegrid.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            preview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            finsihBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            removeBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Picasso.with(this).load(imageUri).into(preview);

            getPhotosList(bubbleName);
            //imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: just added code

Comment: check this out
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html and 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23756716/add-metadata-to-created-bitmap-in-android

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/media/ExifInterface.html -- though I am not aware of an option for what you seek that works with PNG files. EXIF metadata is for JPEG.